# How to append a returned value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to append the returned value of the `parityOf` function in the `appendParity` function. I realize it wouldn't be `return` as I have in my code, but I'm not sure of how to properly append the returned value. Below is my code.

```
def parityOf(list_bits, parity):
    y = parity
    x = list_bits.count(1)

    if (x % 2 == 0 and y % 2 == 0) or (x % 2 != 0 and y % 2 != 0):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

def appendParity(list_bits, parity):
    return list_bits.append(parityOf(return))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but I believe in `appendParity` you want to first calculate the parity bit and then append it to the list. To calculate the parity bit (using `parityOf`), you need to call `parityOf(list_bits, parity)`, not `parityOf(return)` which is invalid syntax. Putting it together, you'd get

```
def appendParity(list_bits, parity):
    return list_bits.append(parityOf(list_bits, parity))
```

Note that the `append` method on lists has the *effect* of appending a value to a list and *returns* `None` (no meaningful value), so the return statement of this function is unnecessary and potentially confusing (you might think it returns the list, but it does not). Perhaps do

```
def appendParity(list_bits, parity):
    list_bits.append(parityOf(list_bits, parity))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def aNum():
...     return 10
...
>>> foo = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> foo.append(aNum())
>>> foo
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost right. But you need to change the return from 
"appendParity" method from `return list_bits.append(parityOf(return))` to
 `return list_bits.append(parityOf(list_bits,parity))`.

notice that "parityOf" method receives 2 parameters